# how to create multiple table in SQLite using properties in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

how can I create multiple tables using entity classes

```
public class Info
    {
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string imageUrl { get; set; }
         [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
         public DetailInfo objDetailInfo{ get; set; }
    }

    public class DetailInfo
    {
        public string phoneno { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using the below code

```
public void createtable()
{
  SQLite.SQLiteConnection db= new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
   db.CreateTable<Info>();
   var data = new Info() { Id = "1", firstName = "Rehan", imageUrl = "safsdfsdf", lastName = "Parvez", objsty = new objDetailInfo{ address = "Nagpur", phoneno = "902136" } };
   db.Insert(data);   

 }
```

while Executing `db.CreateTable<Info>()` it is giving me an Error

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: Anyone got the answer for this? We are in need of solution. Help us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answer my question myself because I think It will help to my other friends 
Use Ignore Keyword

```
public class Info
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string imageUrl { get; set; }
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Ignore]
    public DetailInfo objDetailInfo{ get; set; }
}

public class DetailInfo
{
    public string phoneno { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}

public void createtable()
{
   SQLite.SQLiteConnection db= new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
   db.CreateTable<Info>();
   db.CreateTable<DetailInfo>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-net/) is another way, as documented by sqlite-net,

Summery,

```
public class Stock
{
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(8)]
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
}

public class Valuation
{
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Indexed]
        public int StockId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

With these, you can automatically generate tables in your database by calling CreateTable:

```
var db = new SQLiteConnection("stocks.db");
db.CreateTable<Stock>();
db.CreateTable<Valuation>();
```

You can insert rows in the database using Insert. If the table contains an auto-incremented primary key, then the value for that key will be available to you after the insert:

```
public static void AddStock(SQLiteConnection db, string symbol) {
        var s = db.Insert(new Stock() {
                Symbol = symbol
        });
        Console.WriteLine("{0} == {1}", s.Symbol, s.Id);
}
```

You can query the database using the Query method of SQLiteConnection:

```
public static IEnumerable<Valuation> QueryValuations (SQLiteConnection db, Stock stock)
{
        return db.Query<Valuation> ("select * from Valuation where StockId = ?", stock.Id);
}
```

this query can also be written using Linq syntax so that you type safety and so that your refactors are safe:

```
public static IEnumerable<Valuation> QueryValuations (SQLiteConnection db, Stock stock)
{
        return db.Table<Valuation> ().Where(v => v.StockId == stock.Id);
}
```

The generic parameter to the Query method specifies the type of object to create for each row. It can be one of your table classes, or anyother class whose public properties match the column returned by the query. The Table method requires that a table exists with the same name as the type being returned.

```
public class Val {
        public decimal Money { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
public static IEnumerable<Val> QueryVals (SQLiteConnection db, Stock stock)
{
        return db.Query<Val> ("select \"Price\" as \"Money\", \"Time\" as \"Date\" from Valuation where StockId = ?", stock.Id);
}
```